# Able to select a row but shouldn't select the last column in that row in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, fullrowselect

I have DataGridView with about 5 columns and the last column is a *DataGridViewLinkColumn* type. So the requirement here is that I should be able to select any row I want and when I do that, all the columns should be selected except the last column in that selected row. As the last column contains a hyperlinked text and there are some functions written which are intended to run.

Currently I have set the selection mode to *FullRowSelect*.

To achieve the requirement I have tried to set the mode to CellSelect and in the *CellContentClick* I was setting '*Selected*' property for the specific columns of a selected row. But the selection wasn't happening properly. It would disappear as soon as I click. Also I tried to put the same logic in *CellMouseUp*, but it did't work either.

Kindly suggest me ways or workarounds for achieving the requirement.

Many Thanks!

Comment: _CellContentClick_ Is really serious about its name. Never recommended. _But the selection wasn't happening properly. It would disappear as soon as I click._ Not properly?? Clicked where???

Comment: @TaW CellContentClick is an event I'm referring to here. And I'm clicking on the rows of the DataGridView. When I click, the selection  is not persistent. It goes away quickly. And we won't be able to see if something was selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the `SelectionMode` to `CellSelect`. Then code the `SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell c in dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells)
            c.Selected = c.ColumnIndex != 4;
}
```

Note that this makes no provisions for deselecting a row!